# Function não altera a variável

Tags: php, html

Estou aprendendo a usar functions no php. Criei este html, que irá pegar 3 informações, Nome, raça e classe do jogador:

```
<html>
<head><font face="Arial">
<input type="hidden" name="decicsion" value="0"></head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<div id="start" class="start">
Name:<input type="text" name="n1"><br>
Race:<select name="n2">
<option value="H">Humano</option>
<option value="O">Orc</option>
<option value="E">Elfo</option>
</select><br>
Class:<select name="n3">
<option value="W">Guerreiro</option>
<option value="M">Mago</option>
<option value="A">Arqueiro</option>
</select><br>
<b>
<input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar"></form></div>
<body>';
```

No php, começei criando um algoritmo que salva cada valor, fiz o teste e ele funciona, mostrando todos os valores já definidos.
Cada escolha na classe e raça tem uma alteração em outras variáveis que não citei porque ficaria um trecho de código muito grande.
Basicamente, quando os valores do html forem escolhidos, isso irá aumentar algum atributo do personagem, e dar dois itens para ele

```
if($equip==0)
{
//Define os atributos da classe
if($race=="H")      {$mana=$mana+20; $race="Humano";     }
elseif($race=="O")  {$health=$health+20;    $race="Orc";}
elseif($race=="E")  {$dextery=$dextery+20; $race='Elfo';}

//Adiciona um item de acordo com a classe
if($class=='W'  )   {$sword=1;  $plate=1; $staff=0; $cape=0; $bow=0;    $vest=0; $classe='Guerreiro';}
if($class=='M') {$staff=1;  $cape=1; $plate=0; $sword=0; $bow=0;    $vest=0; $classe='mago';}
if($class=='A') {$bow=1;    $vest=1; $sword=0; $plate=0;    $cape=0; $classe='arqueiro';}

}
```

Eu criei então, vários `if` e `elseif` para aumentar valores do personagem se o item fosse igual a 1. Como esse exemplo:

```
if($sword==1)
{
    $damage=$damage+3; $weapon='Sword'; $sword=3;
}
elseif($sword==2)
{
    $damage=$damage-3;$sword=3;
}
```

Eu fiz isso para cada item que coloquei no trecho das classes, então o código ficou muito extenso e complicado. eu queria transformar esses trechos de código em functions, para poder usar novamente caso eu precisasse. então criei a `function (equipSword)` e passei o código para dentro:

```
//Trecho do código alterado no if
if($class=='W'  )   
{
    equipSword(1);
    $plate=1; 
    $staff=0;   
    $cape=0; 
    $bow=0; 
    $vest=0; 
    $classe='Guerreiro';
}


//defini essa função abaixo do if($equip==0)
function equipSword($sword)
{
if($sword==1){$damage=$damage+3; $weapon='Sword'; $sword=3;}
elseif($sword==2){$damage=$damage-3;$sword=3;} 
if($sword == 3 ){echo'<table style="position:absolute;left:1px;" border="1"><tr><td>Weapon</td><td>Sword</td><tr></table>';}
return $sword;
return $damage;
return $weapon;
}
```

O problema que estou passando, é que mesmo fazendo os returns, as minhas variáveis não mudam, continuam com o mesmo valor. Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado para retornar esses valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que passar como parâmetro os novos valores que você deseja. 
Pois do jeito que você esta fazendo os valores já estão definidos na função.

**exemplo:**

```
$sword = 5;
$damage = 33;
$weapon = "Tword";

$dados = equipSword($sword, $damage, $weapon);
print_r($dados);
```

Função PHP

```
function equipSword($sword, $damage, $weapon){

   if($sword==1){
       $damage = $damage + 3;
       $weapon = $weapon; 
       $sword = $sword;
   }
   elseif($sword == 2){
       $damage = $damage-3;
       $sword = 3;
   } 

   if($sword == 3 ){
       echo'<table style="position:absolute;left:1px;" border="1"><tr> 
       <td>Weapon</td><td>Sword</td><tr></table>';
   }

   $dados = [];
   $dados["sword"] = $sword;
   $dados["damage"] = $damage;
   $dados["weapon"] = $weapon;

   return $dados;
}
```

Comment: Testei seu algoritmo para ver se iria funcionar, o programa enviou o seguinte erro `FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5) : eval()'d code:73 Stack trace: #0 /home4/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5): eval() #1 {main} thrown on line number 73number 73`

Comment: foi por causa do  **$this** na chamada da função. tente novamente código editado.

Comment: Ele agora só exibe a seguinte mensagem: `Array ( [sword] => 1 [damage] => 5 [weapon] => 0 ) `   As variáveis continuam com o valor original

Comment: Você tem que mandar os novos valores como parâmetro, repare como eu fiz la no primeiro exemplo onde eu defini os novos valores para **sword, damage e weapon**. E a partir do momento que a função recebe esses valores você pode trabalhar eles do jeito que você quiser. dai você pode definir um padrão dentro da função onde ela vai realizando sempre.

Comment: Sim, eu fiz exatamente igual

Comment: agora você tem olhar como você está tratando elas dentro da função

Comment: Funcionou depois que eu fiz as variáveis fora dos dados serem iguais ao array. Não era bem isso que eu queria, pois eu queria uma forma que me permitisse chamar a function de um outro lugar com poucas linhas de código. Mas já ajudou, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Há alguns erros conceituais na sua implementação

1 - funções e métodos retornam no primeiro `return` executado, logo, tudo que vem abaixo de `return $sword` não será executado

2 - o return não retorna a variável e sim o valor dela, por isso, vc precisar desse valor, vc deve armazenar o retorno em uma variável, algo do tipo: `$sword=equipSword($sword);`

3 - existe o escopo de variáveis, de forma resumida: as variáveis declaradas fora da função  não são as mesmas que vc chamou dentro, para serem as mesmas vc precisa declarar elas como globais dentro da função, tipo:

```
function equipSword()
{
    global $sword;
    global $damage;
    global $weapon;

    if($sword==1){$damage=$damage+3; $weapon='Sword'; $sword=3;}
    elseif($sword==2){$damage=$damage-3;$sword=3;} 
    if($sword == 3 ){echo'<table style="position:absolute;left:1px;" border="1"><tr><td>Weapon</td><td>Sword</td><tr></table>';}

}
```

Comment: Eu fiz as alterações no código conforme você explicou, mas os valores não mudam mesmo assim